# Java - Merge Base64 PDF

Tags: java

I need do merge multiple base64 pdf files. How can i do this?

```
        OutputStream string = null;

        File file1 = new File(
            "/Users/guilherme.floriano/Desktop/teste1.pdf");
        File file2 = new File(
            "/Users/guilherme.floriano/Desktop/boleto.pdf");

        // Instantiating PDFMergerUtility class

        PDFMergerUtility obj = new PDFMergerUtility();

        // Setting the destination file path

        obj.setDestinationFileName(
            "/Users/guilherme.floriano/Desktop/newMerged.pdf");
        
        // Add all source files, to be merged

        obj.addSource(file1);
        obj.addSource(file2);

        // Merging documents

        obj.mergeDocuments(null);
        
        System.out.print(string);

        System.out.println(
            "PDF Documents merged to a single file");
```

I want this, but, without files, just with base64 strings.

Comment: Sounds like you're just asking "how do I convert a base64 String back into a byte stream?". The fact that they are PDFs is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use PDFBox,  [there is a version of the `addSource()` method that takes an inputStream as parameter](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/PDFMergerUtility.html#addSource(java.io.InputStream)), so you might just consider converting your base64 string into a stream :

```java
String b64data = "....";
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b64data.getBytes());
obj.addSource(Base64.getDecoder().wrap(bais));
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging Base64 strings is very simple you use atob.js or base64 -decode to turn them into binary file objects such as File1.bin File2.bin, then use an appropriate merging tool so for pdfs you use one that can interlace PDF objects (since PDF is a File sandwich of multiple flavours each with a decimal FILE address)

PDF processing is resource intensive so ideally you need to reserve memory for CPU processer interlacing and dump big data (and its still to be decompressed and decoded decimal blocks)to file storage thus its often more effective to work with PDFs as files (which they must be for processing)

MergePDFs -Output Merged.pdf  File1.bin File2.bin

For Java the most common tool to Merge is PDFbox

```
//Instantiating PDFMergerUtility class
      PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
        
      //Setting the destination file
      PDFmerger.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Examples\\merged.pdf");
        
      //adding the source files
      PDFmerger.addSource(file1);
      PDFmerger.addSource(file2);
        
      //Merging the two documents
      PDFmerger.mergeDocuments();
      System.out.println("Documents merged");
```